# slideshow image mouseover dropdown css

Tags: html, css, image, dropdown, slideshow

I made a automatic image slideshow.
I want to make a dropdown image when I mouseover the slideshow image.
I have put dropdown css, html code but it didn't work. Is there any solution for this?

[css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phtP1.png)
[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbvZc.png)

I want to make a dropdown image when I mouseover the slideshow image.

Comment: Please don't use images for code and please provide relevant code blocks to show us what you have attempted to do.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because the '`height`' attribute is missing in css.
Here is your code simplified and it works fine:

```css
.dd {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-blick;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.dc {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: silver;
}

.dd:hover .dc {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='dd sl'>
  <div class='dc'>

  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, it is better no to write styles inside the markup style attribute but inside the css file or block.